# reactjs axios post request throwing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, post, axios

I have a function that gets data from a form when it is submitted and I am trying to make a post request using axios with this data here is my function (reactjs):

```js
const handelSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newFact = {Email, Fact, Source};
        axios.post('https://www.examplesite.com/create', {
          "data": newFact})
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          })
    }
```

here's part of the code for the example site (nodejs):

```js
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
Accept');
    next();
});

app.get("/", async function(req, res) {
    const result = await randomfact();
    res.send(result);
    console.log(randomfact());
});

app.post('/create', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});

let port = process.env.PORT;
if(port == null || port == "") {
   port = 8000;
}

app.listen(port, function() {
   console.log("Server started successfully");
});
```

my problem is that the post request doesn't seem to be making it to the example site here's the error I got:

```
VM2633:1 POST https://www.examplesite.com/create net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
(anonymous) @ VM2633:1
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:177
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:13
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:61
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:87
wrap @ bind.js:9
handelSubmit @ Modal.js:14
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22413
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)

createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)
```

Comment: looks dns issue. Please check `https://www.examplesite.com/create` this url is working. ry to post via postman and check if it's working

Comment: I made a post request using reqbin.com and it worked perfectly fine so I'm pretty sure its an issue with my code and not the dns, to confirm this I deployed the site and ran it and still got the same error

Comment: Ok, so this is happening from your deployment server? You can check firewall setting if blocking it.

Comment: I was able to fix my issue by rewriting my post command

Comment: it turns out that this only fixed the problem when running it on local host but when I tried to deploy it says Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 405 not sure why it only works on local host the error code would mean that post requests arent allowed but I was just able to make one from local host which makes no sense

Comment: Can you check the network tab if host name or url is not misconfigured from env file?